# How do I make a nuget package target multiple frameworks correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, class-library, dnx

Currently, I get the following error:

```
Could not install package 'csharp-extensions 1.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/csharp-extensions
The Nuget Link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/csharp-extensions/1.2.0

In my project.json, I specify dnx46 and dnxcore50

```
{
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "configurations": {
        "Debug": {
            "compilationOptions": {
                "define": [ "DEBUG", "TRACE" ]
            }
        },
        "Release": {
            "compilationOptions": {
                "define": [ "RELEASE", "TRACE" ],
                "optimize": true
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-*",
        "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-*",
        "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*"
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "csharp_extensions",
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx46": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
                "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-beta-*",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.11-beta-*",
                "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "4.0.11-beta-*",
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-*",
                "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-*"
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "_": "this is the recommended windows runtime",
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
                "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-beta-*",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "(4.0,]",
                "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "(4.0.0,]",
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "(4.0.0,]",
                "System.IO": "(4.0,]"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

The project I'm trying to install the nuget into is a Class Library targeting .NET Framework 4.6 (and isn't a dnx project)

UPDATE:

This is what happens when I build the nuget package with `nuget pack`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the project.json configuration that eventually allowed this nuget to work with non-dnx projects:

https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/csharp-extensions/blob/2767e8ae87dcc69a14d1a33fd63b9eef364ee1ec/project.json

the key parts were (under frameworks)

```
 "net46": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Runtime": {
                    "type": "build",
                    "version": ""
                }
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-*",
                "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "4.0.11-beta-*",
                "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-*",
                "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-beta-*",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.11-beta-*",
            }

        },
```

and

using the generic test runners for xunit:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-*",
    "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
    "xunit.runners": "2.0.0",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your csharp-extensions NuGet package it looks incorrect. It has your project files and no assemblies.

I assume this was generated by running `NuGet.exe package package.nuspec`. This will not generate a NuGet package that can be used from NuGet.org since there are no assemblies.

If you build your .xproj in Visual Studio it will generate a .nupkg in the artifacts directory for you if you have `Product outputs on build` checked in the project options, which you have. Unfortunately this .nupkg file, whilst it has assemblies, only has a lib\dnxcore50 directory and NuGet will not allow you to install it into a .NET 4.6 project since NuGet finds them to be incompatible. Using the .nupkg file in the artifacts directory returns the same error. You only seem to be able to install this artifact .nupkg into a DNX project (Console or Web app) but not a DNX Class Library project.

I would take a look at existing NuGet packages and try to generate the same structure. Looking at System.Xml.XmlDocument for example has the new NuGet 3 style directory structure:

```
\lib
    \dotnet
    \net46
\ref
    \dotnet
    \net46
```

Only the directories above have the System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll in them.

NuGet 2 would have just the lib directory and does not support dotnet as a directory.

Comment: I've been using the `nuget pack` command to generate the .nupkg -- and it doesn't put anything in the lib folder -- Is it supposed to be automatic? I do get a warning  when I build: (see update in question). Also, how do I build the non dnxcore50 dll?

Comment: even when I manually make a lib/dnx46 folder and drag csharp-extensions.dll into, I still get that warning in the screenshot...

Comment: It will put assemblies into the lib folder. However you need to either explicitly have them in your .nuspec or have the folders layed out above the .nuspec so NuGet uses them. See the [Creating a NuGet package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) documentation.

Comment: Is there a different guide anywhere? I've seen that one, and I don't understand how to apply what it's saying to my project

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I generally explicitly list the files in the .nuspec file. Here is one [.nuspec](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/blob/master/src/AddIns/Misc/PackageManagement/Packages/AvalonEdit/AvalonEdit.nuspec). The source files do not need to be added. Adding them allows you to generate a symbols package so other people can debug your NuGet package.

Comment: using `dotnet pack` I didn't get any errors, when building / pushing. BUt, I still got the same error about the package not containing any assembly references or contents files that are compatible with .net46

Comment: Not tried dotnet pack. I would look inside the .nupkg, it is just a .zip file, and see what has been created.

Comment: the .nupkg has dnxcore50 and dnx46 folders with the ddls inside them, so that's good. Maybe it's an incompatibility thing with dnx46 and regular .net46? (the project I'm trying to use this nuget in isn't a dnx project)